# redirecting to same position after selecting a checkbox from grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery, redirect

I have a table where in i have a column of check-box. After user selects a particular check-box, suppose from row 20, and perform necessary actions, i want to call the grid but it should point to the row i have selected check-box. But currently it is not happening. Instead of window.location, what can be other method? I hope you got my question. Please help. Thanks in advance! Following is my code-

```
 function UpdateStatus(status, id, cb) {
    var Status = status;
    var Id = id;
    var projectId = $("#projectId").val();
    if ($("#" + status + id).is(':checked')) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            var data = { Status: Status, Id: Id, projectId: projectId };
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("EditDispatchStatus", "BOM")',
                type: 'GET',
                data: data,
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                     window.location = '@Url.Action("DispatchStatus","BOM")?Id=' + data.result;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firs things first you should remove the `async: false` option, because this is a blocking call, not an AJAX call and is very bad.

Now to your actual question. Here's how you could get the containing row:

```
function UpdateStatus(status, id, cb) {
    var Status = status;
    var Id = id;
    var projectId = $("#projectId").val();
    var $checkbox = $("#" + status + id);
    if ($checkbox.is(':checked')) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            var data = { Status: Status, Id: Id, projectId: projectId };
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("EditDispatchStatus", "BOM")',
                type: 'GET',
                data: data,
                context: $checkbox.closest('tr'),
                success: function (data) {
                    // this will point to the <tr> that was clicked
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how we are passing as `context: $checkbox.closest('tr')` to the success callback. So inside this callback `this` will point to the `<tr>` row that was clicked. You could use it in order to do something with it.

Comment: no, this dint work! What needs to be done inside the success call back. Window.location should be kept as it is?

Comment: `window.location.href` will redirect you away from the current page. If you want to stay on the same page and just refresh some portion of the DOM you could use the technique described in my answer. As I already explained `this` will point to the `<tr>` of the row that was clicked. Then depending on what your controller action returned, you could find the corresponding element that you want to update and call the `.html` method on it. But once again it will depend on your specific requirements.

Comment: i want to load the page with grid that points to specific check box row selected.